# Rainbow Table - Number of Chains and Chain Length

Tags: hash, rainbow-table

Is there a difference between having 10,000 of chains (with 1,000 chain length) and 10,000 chain length (with 1,000 of chains)? How does it affect the success rate of the rainbow table?

I understand that only start point and end point are kept in the table. The more chains you have, the disk space increases. Whereas the higher number of chain length would mean longer computing time is required to run through them.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compute these without a lot of other parameters, the most basic being the size of the keyspace you are searching, are you using perfect vs non-perfect rainbow tables, etc. See, e.g., [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/540.pdf) on eprint for the gory details.